# SVG image not visible in android 3.0+ with same code

Tags: android, svg, android-imageview, svg-android

I have a test app where I have got a ListView with an item which contains two images on it.

[image: nexus 7 vs. desire hd]

As you can see in the API 17 device does not display the play button (SVG image) while the API 10 device does that. How can I fix that?

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forceground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my basic code where I set the images:

```
View preview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video_preview, parent, false);
ImageView background = (ImageView)preview.findViewById(R.id.background);
ImageView forceground = (ImageView)preview.findViewById(R.id.forceground);
PictureDrawable play = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(parent.getResources(), R.raw.play_blue).createPictureDrawable();
forceground.setImageDrawable(play);
```

The SVG paser is from [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/).

Comment: where are you setting background imageview

Comment: With a complex callback where the image is downloaded from the web. Lets say I don't beleve that this causes the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is the hardware acceleration. The solution is to use bitmaps instad of drawables. For fixing that I added this function to the `SVG.java` which returns a `BitmapDrawable`:

```
public BitmapDrawable createBitmapDrawable(Context context) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    PictureDrawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, except that it causes scaling issues. But it is fine for regular low-intensity usage.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with your solution is that you are losing all the drawing information when converting it to a `Bitmap`. In your case it doesn't apply, but if you needed to support `Zooming` and `Panning`, you would be scaling and resizing a `Bitmap` and would get pixelated graphics. Additionally it's much more inefficient to draw a `Picture` into a `Bitmap` which will then be drawn by the `View` that contains it.

I had the same problem you experienced and solved it by turning off hardware acceleration only on the view that will draw the `Picture`:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

However [setLayerType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) is only supported since API 11. So use this method instead:

```
public static void setHardwareAccelerated(View view, boolean enabled){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        if(enabled)
            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        else view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to check if the API exists with something like `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)`. I'll need to check this.

Comment: Yes, true. I used the code from an example I saw and didn't remember it would be simpler like that ;) Thanks, will change my answer when I test that.

Comment: +1 This answer avoids blurriness unlike the accepted answer in which it's possible one does not know canvas size ahead of time, like for an `ImageView` being inflated in a `GridView` adapter.